# sort objects in outliner case-insensitive

Tags: outliner

I really love blender but what puts me off a little bit is the case-sensitive sorting in the outliner.

[image]

Mostly I use lower case object names, but freshly created objects always have an upper case first character. The only option available here is to disable alphabetical sorting, but that's counterproductive in my case.

So, does anybody know an addon or something to achieve case-insensitive sorting?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no need in addon for the thing like that.

The software put a new object name with an upper case because of python script in the source code that define an objects' (for example cube) name with upper case. So the solutions are:

1. Name your objects with a capital letter
2. Rewrite source files. I mean put cube instead of Cube in every file where it is. But it's time consuming

PS

You can create new objects on the separate layer with enabled option "visible layers" in outliner

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but rewriting the source code is no real option for me. And always trying to use lower case characters is just kind of working around the software – sometimes I use german nouns, and they start with a capital letter. A real solution would be really appreciated.